# Handling cache warm-up with twisted and systemd

Tags: twisted

I have a simple twisted application which I run using a systemd service, executing a script, which subsequently executes a .tac file.

The application is structured as a JSON RPC endpoint (fastjsonrpc), built into a t.w.r.Resource, which is in a t.w.s.Site, and served t.a.i.TCPServer, and the whole thing packed into a t.a.Application. This works fine.

Where I do run into trouble is when I try to warm up caches at startup. This warm-up process is pretty slow (~300 seconds), and makes systemd timeout and kill the process. Increasing the timeout is not really a viable option, since I wouldn't want this to block system boot.

Analogous code is used in a separate stack running on Flask from within Apache and wsgi. That server starts itself off and lets systemd go on while it takes its time building the caches. This behaviour is fine for me.

I've tried calling the warmup function using the following within the setup function of the t.w.r.Resource:

```
reactor.callLater(1, ep.warmup, None)
```

I've not yet tried using this from within systemd, and have been testing it from twistd directly on the command line. The server does work as expected, however it no longer responds to SIGINT (^C). Removing the callLater is all that's needed to let the server respond to SIGINT.

If the warmup function is called directly (not by callLater, i.e., the arrangement which makes systemd give up while waiting for warm up to complete), the resulting server also continues to respond to SIGINT.

1. Is there a better / good way to handle this sort of long-running warmup code?
2. Why would twistd / the reactor not respond to SIGINT? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Twisted is a single-threaded thing. It sounds like your "cache warmup" code is blocking the reactor for those 300 seconds. One easy way to fix this would be using `deferToThread` to let it run without blocking the reactor.

Comment: I have no problem with it blocking the reactor for that 300 seconds, but I need the reactor to be normally responsive after that. The reactor works as normal otherwise, but no longer responds to SIGINT/SIGTERM, and needs SIGKILL to be stopped. deferToThread is not likely to work well for me because my cache is pretty complicated network of python objects.

Comment: Alternatively, you could re-write your "warmup" routine to return a Deferred and thus yield control to the reactor periodically. I'm not sure if/how this could be related to the signal behavior you see .. but it's a better way to do it. One way is to just use @inlineCallbacks and "yield" every so many loop-iterations (if it's a loop).